If a process satisfy the "affine property" is it a Markov processes?
Let $X$ be a stochastic process valued in $\mathbf{R}^d$ that, given a $d$-dimensional row vector $u$ and under suitable integrability conditions, satisfies:
\begin{equation}
E[\exp(uX_T)|\mathcal{F}_t] = \exp(\phi(T-t)+\psi(T-t)X_t)
\end{equation}
where the real-valued function $\phi$ and row-vector-valued function $\psi$ satisfy the Riccati equations:
$$
\phi(t) =\int_0^t (\psi(s)b_0+ \frac{1}{2} \psi(s) A_0 \psi(s)^{\mathsf{T}}) ds,
$$
$$
\psi = u + \int_0^t (\psi(s)B + \frac{1}{2} A (\psi(s))) ds,
$$
with $A(u) =(uA^1u^{\mathsf{T}}, \ldots, u A^du^{\mathsf{T}})$ and $B=(b^1, \ldots, b^d)$.
Can I conclude that $X$ is Markov according to The Markov property for Ito diffusions? (see e.g. Oksendal-Partial Differential Equations Thm 7.1.2)
The definition of an affine process (see e.g., Definition 2.1 in https://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~schachermayer/pubs/preprnts/prpr0142.pdf) requires the process $X$ to be Markovian. Therefore, I am inquiring whether a process whose characteristic function is exponentially affine with respect to the state vector is a Markov process.
Any reference to a paper or book is extremely welcomed. Thank you!
